# How to append sed hold space to later match?

Tags: sed

I have a file with contents:

```
Create view xyz1 as Select
field1,
field2,
field3,
field4

Create view xyz2 as Select
field1,
field2,
field3,
field4
```

I am thinking i can use sed hold space to capture the 'Create view' line and then print it at the next empty line(ie after field4)?  I could not quite find this scenario on the interwebs, is it possible?
So it would look like this:

```
Create view xyz1 as Select
field1,
field2,
field3,
field4
Create view xyz1 as Select
Create view xyz2 as Select
field1,
field2,
field3,
field4
Create view xyz2 as Select
```

thanks

Comment: Take a look at sed's commands `h` and `g`.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` may not be the best solution, try `awk`

```
awk '/Create/ {s=$0} /^$/ {$0=s} 1; END {print s}' file
Create view xyz1 as Select
field1,
field2,
field3,
field4
Create view xyz1 as Select
Create view xyz2 as Select
field1,
field2,
field3,
field4
Create view xyz2 as Select
```

Comment: Didn't vote down. Solution with `sed` is shorter and in my opinion more understandable if you know what commands `h` and `g` do.